# Find $\int [2\sin^{-1}(\frac x 4)+2\sin(2\sin^{-1}(\frac x 4)]dx$

Tags: integration

Solve the following indefinite integral:$$\int [2\sin^{-1}(\frac x 4)+2\sin(2\sin^{-1}(\frac x 4)]dx$$

My thoughts so far:
The possible derivates and antiderivatives of $\arcsin$ seem too messy to use substitution. I guess we can try breaking the integral into

$$2\int \sin^{-1}(\frac x 4)dx+2\int \sin(\sin^{-1}(\frac x 4))dx$$

Where to go from here? (I don't know how to solve either of these integrals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the substitution $x=4\sin \theta$ to get $$I=8\int \theta\cos \theta d\theta +8\int \sin 2\theta\cos \theta  d\theta $$ The second integral is straightforward and the first integral can be easily evaluated using integration by parts.

Comment: Just beat me to it.  But shouldn't the second one have $\sin2\theta$ instead of $\sin\theta$?

Comment: Oops, sorry, you're correct. I am editing that.

Comment: Thanks, all three answers were very elegant but this was the simplest

Answer (score 1):

Substitution might not be that messy after all.

$$u=2\sin^{-1}\frac x4$$
$$\frac x4=\sin\frac u2$$
$$x=4\sin\frac u2,dx=2\cos\frac u2du$$

This reduces our integral to

$$2\int(u+2\sin u)\cos\frac u2du=$$
$$2\int u\cos\frac u 2du+8\int\sin\frac u2\cos^2\frac u2du$$

The first half can be done by integration by parts and the second by simple substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$
\sin \left(2\sin^{-1}(x/4)\right)=2\sin\left(\sin^{-1}(x/4)\right)\cos\left(\sin^{-1}(x/4)\right)=2\dfrac{x}{4}\sqrt{1-\dfrac{x^2}{16}}
$$

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful- but how did you know that $\cos (\sin^{-1}(\frac x 4))=\sqrt {1 - \frac {x^2} {16}}$?

Comment: since: $\sin(\sin^{-1}(x/4))=x/4$ by definition, and $\cos \alpha=\sqrt{1-\sin^2 \alpha}$.